# how to create a measure YTD by mutiples items

Tags: filter, dax, powerpivot, measure

On power pivot, I have difficulties to calculate YTD from a measure.

Total YTD is correct, however if I insert a column the YTD by item is not correct.

[image]

```
  =IF (
        HASONEVALUE ( Data[Year] ),
        CALCULATE (
            measure,
            FILTER (
                ALL ( Data ),
                Data[Year] = VALUES ( Data[Year] )
                    && Data[date] <= MAX ( Data[date] )
                )
        ),
        BLANK()
    )
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Your question will be hard to answer without an image of your data model, and DAX code for the "measure 1". Also, a description  of a desired outcome will help a lot.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, for measure = sum of hit of orders / sum of orders, this one works perfectly, the outcome expected is a cumulative (YTD) of this measure week by week. My formula works for the total, but doesn't work for each item. from the picture above (in green) right result calculated, in (orange) wrongly calculated, it shows for each items the total result YTD

Answer (score 0):

finally I could solved it:

-> week in table was in format text, so I convert into numbers e.g.(1901 instead of wk1901)

-> filter formula was not correct, so now I'm calculating week min to max week 
(FILTER(ALL(Data[Weeks]), Data[Weeks] <= MAX(Data[Weeks])))

Thanks!